# does mutex::lock() wait for other thread to unlock

Tags: c++, multithreading

if one thread lock the critical section and the second thread arrive to `lock()`. this last one wait there ? he doesn't reach "`other stuff`" after `unlock()` till the first thread unlock the mutex ?

```
std::mutex mtx;           // mutex for critical section

void print_thread_id (int id) {
// critical section (exclusive access to std::cout signaled by locking mtx):
mtx.lock();
std::cout << "thread #" << id << '\n';
mtx.unlock();
/// other stuff
}

int main ()
{
std::thread threads[10];
// spawn 10 threads:
for (int i=0; i<10; ++i)
    threads[i] = std::thread(print_thread_id,i+1);

for (auto& th : threads) th.join();

return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's the whole idea of a mutex yes, only allowing one thread at a time (no guarantees about the order in which they are let through though). Also note, its better to use std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock{mtx}; because that will do the unlock regardless of how you leave a scope/function. (e.g. imagine what happens in your case if std::cout would throw an exception)

Comment: Why don't you add some more prints to find out ;)? It doesn't reach your print either, it just stays at the `mtx.lock()` until the mutex becomes available. To be precise however, if you have multiple threads waiting on a mutex, the "unlock order" may differ between runs.